# How to prove that $O(n) \cdot O(n^2) = O(n^3)$?

Tags: asymptotics

Would the solution be something like

let $fn \in O(n)$ so $ fn \le c1 \cdot n$  and  $ gn \in O(n^2) $ so $ gn \le c2 \cdot n^2$ where $c1,c2$ constants

so $ fn*gn \le C \cdot n^3$ so $ fn*gn \in O(n^3)$ so $O(n) \cdot O(n^2) = O(n^3)$

Comment: As you are properly using $\in$, I suppose that the target equality is indeed supposed to be an equality among sets. In that case, you only show $O(n)\cdot O(n^2)\subseteq O(n^3)$ and need to show $O(n^3)\subseteq O(n)\cdot O(n^2)$ as well

Comment: This proves that $O(n)\cdot O(n^2)\subseteq O(n^3)$. Now to the other inclusion!

Comment: would another possible solution be let $fn \in Θ(n)$ so $c1 \cdot n\le fn \le c2 \cdot n$  and  $ gn \in Θ(n^2) $ so $c3 \cdot n^2\le gn \le c4 \cdot n^2$ 

so $c1 \cdot n \cdot c3 \cdot n^2\le fn \cdot gn \le c2 \cdot n \cdot c4 \cdot n^2$ so $ c5 \cdot n^3 \le fn \cdot gn \le c6 \cdot n^3$

that means $ Θ(n^3) \subseteq fn \cdot gn \subseteq Θ(n^3)$ so $ fn \cdot gn =Θ(n^3)$ which also means $ fn \cdot gn =O(n^3)$ so  $O(n) \cdot O(n^2) = O(n^3)$

Comment: No, the missing inclusion is $O(n^3)\subseteq O(n)\cdot O(n^2)$, that is, the assertion that, for every sequence $(x_n)$ in $O(n^3)$, there exists some sequences $(y_n)$ in $O(n)$ and $(z_n)$ in $O(n^2)$ such that $x_n=y_nz_n$ for every $n$. This is not terribly difficult to prove, but... can you prove it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are exactly right.

Maybe even $$fn \cdot gn \leq c_1 n \cdot c_2 n^2 \leq C n^3 = O(n^3)$$ for more clarity.

---

**note:** When speaking of complexity classes, the equality sign is often used insted of $\in$ which would be formally more correct.

If you also need to prove $O(n^3) \subseteq O(n) \cdot O(n^2)$, the argument would go <s>the same</s> similarly (see comments below for details).

Comment: "the argument would go the same, backwards." Hmmm... how so?

Comment: Let $f \in O(n^3)$. Then there exist $g \in O(n)$ and $h \in O(n^2)$ such that $f = g \cdot h$. Am I missing something?

Comment: Which $g$? Which $h$? Asserting these exist is no proof.

Comment: If $f$ happens to be in $O(n)$, we can define $g:=f$ and $h:=C$. Similar if $f \in O(n^2)$. Otherwise, we define $g:=f/n^2$ and $h:=f/g$

Comment: Right. Finally something close to a complete proof.

Answer (score 0):

First, there seems to be some confusion about what you are asked to prove: what does $$\tag{1} O(n) \cdot O(n^2) = O(n^3)$$ mean, exactly?

The interpretation I'm familiar with, in the words of Cormen et al., is the following:

> In some cases, asymptotic notation appears on the left-hand side of an equation,
>   as in $$2n^2 + \Theta(n) = \Theta(n^2)\text{ .}$$
>   We interpret such equations using the following rule: *No matter how the anonymous
>   functions are chosen on the left of the equal sign, there is a way to choose
>   the anonymous functions on the right of the equal sign to make the equation valid.*

(Cormen et al., "Introduction to Algorithms", 3rd Ed., section 3.1, page 50.)

Note how this makes the $\;=\;$ operator *asymmetrical*.  Note also that this makes $\;f(n) = O(g(n))\;$ mean $\;f \in O(g(n))\;$.

$%
\require{begingroup}
\begingroup
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\op}[1]{\\ #1 \quad & \quad \unicode{x201c}}
\newcommand{\hints}[1]{\mbox{#1} \\ \quad & \quad \phantom{\unicode{x201c}} }
\newcommand{\hint}[1]{\mbox{#1} \unicode{x201d} \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}
\newcommand{\Ref}[1]{\text{(#1)}}
\newcommand{\then}{\Rightarrow}
\newcommand{\when}{\Leftarrow}
%$This interpretation says that $\Ref{1}$ is equivalent to: $$
\begin{align}&
\langle \forall f,g :: f \in O(n) \;\land\; g \in O(n^2) \;\then\;
\\&\phantom{\langle \forall f,g ::\;}
\langle \exists h :: h \in O(n^3) \;\land\; \langle \forall n :: f(n) \cdot g(n) = h(n) \rangle \rangle \rangle
\end{align}
$$ or simplified: for all $\;f,g\;$, $$
\tag{1a}
f(n) = O(n) \;\land\; g(n) = O(n^2) \;\then\; f(n) \cdot g(n) = O(n^3)
$$

---

Now, how would we prove $\Ref{1a}$?  You have the correct idea essentially, and let's try to write this down as cleanly as possible, using the definition that you seem to be using, which is $$
\tag{2}
f(n) = O(g(n)) \;\equiv\; \langle \exists c : c > 0 : \langle \forall_{\text{large enough }} n :: f(n) \le c \cdot g(n) \rangle \rangle
$$

It seems simplest to start with $\;f(n) \cdot g(n)\;$, and rewrite that using the assumptions in the left hand side of $\Ref{1a}$:

$$\calc
    f(n) \cdot g(n)
\op{\le_{\forall_{\text{large enough }} n}}\hints{using the LHS of $\Ref{1a}$ and definition $\Ref{2}$ twice,}\hint{choose $\;c_1,c_2 > 0\;$}
    c_1 \cdot n \cdot c_2 \cdot n^2
\op=\hint{arithmetic}
    (c_1 \cdot c_2) \cdot n^3
\op=\hint{using definition $\Ref{2}$ with $\;c := c_1 \cdot c_2\;$}
    O(n^3)
\endcalc$$

By transitivity of the three steps, this proves $\Ref{1a}$.

---

A side note: The above proof of course doesn't just work for $\;n\;$ and $\;n^2\;$, but for any functions $\;F(n),G(n)\;$: in the same way we can prove the more general $$\tag{3} O(F(n)) \cdot O(G(n)) = O(F(n) \cdot G(n))$$

---

Finally, what about proving the other direction?  I would write this as $$\tag{4} O(n^3) = O(n) \cdot O(n^2)$$
and Cormen et al. says this means we need to prove
\begin{align}
\tag{4a}
&\langle \forall f :: f \in O(n^3) \;\then\;
\\&\phantom{\langle \forall f :: \;}
\langle \exists g,h :: g \in O(n) \land h \in O(n^2) \land
\\&\phantom{\langle \forall f :: \langle \exists g,h :: \;}
\langle \forall n :: f(n) = g(n) \cdot h(n) \rangle \rangle \rangle
\end{align}

So given an $\;f \in O(n^3)\;$, there seem to be two simple choices, one of which is $\;g(n) = f(n) / n^2\;$, and $\;h(n) = n^2\;$.  All that is then left to prove is $\;f(n)/n^2 = O(n)\;$ and $\;n^2 = O(n^2)\;$, which are easy exercises from definition $\Ref{2}$.

(Note that I'm assuming here that $\;n\;$ ranges over positive integers, to avoid technical manipulations to avoid division by zero.)

And again, of course this proof generalizes immediately to a proof of $$O(F(n) \cdot G(n)) = O(F(n)) \cdot O(G(n))$$

The only qualm I have with this proof is that it isn't really symmetrical in $\;g\;$ and $\;h\;$: we could have equally well have chosen $\;g(n) = n\;$ and $\;h(n) = f(n) / n\;$.  I tried to find a more symmetrical choice for $\;g,h\;$, but don't see it yet.

$%
\endgroup
%$

Answer (score -1):

Recall that

$$O(n)=\omega_1(n)\cdot n \quad \limsup_{n\to \infty} |\omega_1 (n)|=c_1\in \mathbb{R}$$

$$O(n^2)=\omega_2(n)\cdot n^2 \quad \limsup_{n\to \infty} |\omega_2 (n)|=c_2\in \mathbb{R}$$

therefore

$$O(n) \cdot O(n^2)=\omega_1 (n)\cdot\omega_2(n)\cdot n^3=\omega_3(n)\cdot n_3=O(n^3)$$

indeed

$$\limsup\left|\omega_3(n)\right|\le\limsup\left|\omega_1 (n)\right|\cdot \limsup\left|\omega_2(n)\right|=c_1\cdot c_2=c_3\in \mathbb{R}$$

Comment: something wrong with the proof through limsup?